# [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in MERN Stack Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

How to make user redirect after authentication based on `user.role` ?
I'm getting the following error: **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const { COOKIE_NAME, SECRET } = require('../config/config')

module.exports = function() {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        let token = req.cookies[COOKIE_NAME]
        if(token) {
            jwt.verify(token, SECRET, function(err, decoded){
                if (err) {
                    res.clearCookie(COOKIE_NAME)
                } else {
                    if(decoded.user.role === 'admin') {
                        res.redirect('http://localhost:4000')
                    }
                    req.user = decoded;
                }
            })
        }
        next();
    }
}
```

Login Fetch:

```
  fetch(`${API}/auth/login`,{
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
            })
            .then((response) => {
                if(response.status === 302) {
                    window.location = 'http://localhost:4000'
                }
                else if(response.status === 200) { 
                    onSuccess()
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        window.location = '/'
                    }, 1000)
                } else if (response.status === 401) {
                    onError()
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
```

Here is my authService:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const User = require('../models/User');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const { SALT_ROUNDS, SECRET } = require('../config/config');

const register =  async ({name, username, email, password, cart})  => {

    let salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_ROUNDS);
    let hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const user = new User({
        name,
        username,
        email,
        password: hash,
        cart
    });
    return await user.save()
}

const login = async ({email, password}) => {
    
        let user = await User.findOne({email})
        if (!user) {
            throw {message: 'User not found!'}
        }

        let isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        if (!isMatch) {
            throw {message: 'Password does not match!'}
        }

        let token = jwt.sign({user}, SECRET)
        
        return token;
}
```

And my authController:

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const authService = require('../services/authService');
const { COOKIE_NAME } = require('../config/config');

const router = Router();

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body
    try {
        let token = await authService.login({email, password})
        res.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, token)
        res.status(200).json(token)
        } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({ error: error })
    }
})
```

Here is my server if this will help:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:4000'];
    const origin = req.headers.origin;
    if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
         res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
         res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
    }
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});
```

Comment: The error is coming because you have `next();` after `res.end()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya same error if I switch them. And no, I didn't find anything there

Comment: You don't need to switch. You have to remove `next();`

Comment: I can't login without next

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `jwt.verify` with a callback, it is being executed asynchronously. Due to this, immediately after calling `verify` but before getting the decoded token, your `next()` function is called which passes the control to the next middleware (which probably would be synchronous) which then returns the request.

The flow of events would be something like this:

- `if(token) { ...`  starts
- `jwt.verify(token, ...` is called asynchronously. It registers the callback `function(err, decoded) { ...` but doesn't execute it yet.
- You exit the `if(token) { ... }` block and call `next()`.
- The next middleware in line starts executing and probably returns the request if it is the last middleware in chain. ***So the client has already been sent the response by this time***.
- `jwt.verify(token ...` succeeds and calls your registered callback.
- It sees that there is no error at line `if (err) ...` so it moves to the else block.
- It decodes the user role and tries to redirect (which internally would try to insert a header on the response). But this fails because the user was already sent the response (and hence your error message).

So the simple solution to this is to not call `next()` **UNTIL** jwt verifies and decodes your token and you know the role. In the code below, I've moved the `next()` function call a few lines upwards.

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const { COOKIE_NAME, SECRET } = require('../config/config')

module.exports = function() {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        let token = req.cookies[COOKIE_NAME]
        if(token) {
            jwt.verify(token, SECRET, function(err, decoded){
                if (err) {
                    res.clearCookie(COOKIE_NAME)
                } else {
                    if(decoded.user.role === 'admin') {
                        res.redirect('http://localhost:4000')
                    }
                    req.user = decoded;
                }
                next();
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u check my login fetch request? Now the request stays on pending, and after 3/4 minutes it failed

Comment: Are you receiving cookies on the backend? Do the cookies have the token?

Comment: You can check my authService and Controller

Comment: In your frontend code, you have added a case for handling 200 and a case for handling 401. But in your backend code, since you are calling `res.redirect()`, your frontend will be receiving a code of 302 ( as can be seen [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) ). Add a case for when `response.status === 302`

Comment: Okay, you can check my fetch request again, if I get it right, but if I'm now I'm getting the following error: `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/auth/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:5000/' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors'... `

Comment: I provide part of my server.js I think it will help

Comment: And the middleware is the same as yours

Comment: You have three port numbers in play: 3000, 4000, 5000. Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233688/discussion-between-yollo-and-thanatonian2311).